# Did Allah create a being of absolute evil?

Tags: allah

If Allah created angel who are absolute good. Does that mean he create reverse of them? I mean Allah always creates duality.

Comment: Can you give an example of a being that is "Absolute Good"? (Angels are not inherently good or evil as they have no self choice)